# jquery объеденить запросы

Tags: jquery, post

Есть jquery код с двумя post запросами, первый обрабатывает форму, второй файлы. Как сделать чтобы все отправлялась одним пост запросом?

```
//Сохранение страницы
    $j('.save').click(function (e) {
        var cont = $j('.edit').serialize();
        $j.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'edit.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: cont,
            success: function (response) {
                $j(".result-files-upload").html(response); // Файл загружен
                $j(".result-files-upload").fadeIn();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $j(".result-files-upload").fadeOut()
                }, 1500);
            },
            error: function (xhr, str) {
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
        });

        var inp = $j('input[name="editimg"]').val();
        if (inp == "yes") {
            var formData = new FormData($j(".sendfileform")[0]);
            $j.ajax({
                url: 'edit.php', //куда отправить данные
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'html',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (response) {

                    $j(".result-files-upload").html(response); // Файл загружен
                    $j(".result-files-upload").fadeIn();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $j(".result-files-upload").fadeOut()
                    }, 1500);

                }
            });
        }


    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, просто объединил запросы

```
var formData = new FormData($j(".edit")[0]);

        $j.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'edit.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $j(".result-files-upload").html(response); // Файл загружен
                $j(".result-files-upload").fadeIn();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $j(".result-files-upload").fadeOut()
                }, 1500);
            },
            error: function (xhr, str) {
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
        });
```